# Timer with callback (vanilla) throws TypeError

Tags: javascript

let me start with: I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I am trying to realize a timer with a callback function. when it runs it throws an error (typeError, callback is not a function).

can someone point me in the right direction/show me what I am missing?
thank you,

Cathy

my code:

```
let time = 0;
let myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function doSomething(){
  console.log("something")
}

function myTimer(callback) {
  if (time === 10) {
    clearInterval(myVar);
    // excecute
    callback();
  } else {
    time++;
    console.log(time);
  }
}

myTimer(doSomething);

// output: 
// 1
// 2
// 3 
// (...)
// TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the callback parameter isn't actually being passed to the interval, and is only being run once. Basically, the `myTimer(doSomething)` only runs once, while `time` is less than 3. Then, the myTimer from the setInterval keeps on running, which doesn't have the callback parameter. By the time the if statement is successful, there is no callback parameter, so it doesn't work.

Instead, you should use an anonymous function in the setInterval so that you can call myTimer with a parameter.

```js
let time = 0;
let myVar = setInterval(() => myTimer(doSomething), 1000);

function doSomething() {
  console.log("something")
}

function myTimer(callback) {
  if (time === 3) {
    clearInterval(myVar);
    // excecute
    callback();
  } else {
    time++;
    console.log(time);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as lemondoge mentioned you forgot to pass the function argument.

Here is a way that i like to do stuff, a bit more readable and reusable i think.

```js
var timer = {
    counter: 0,
    timer: null,
    callback: null,
    stop: 10,

    start: function(callback, speed) {
        this.callback = callback;
        var self = this;
        this.timer = setInterval(function() {
            if (self.counter == self.stop) {
                clearInterval(self.timer)
                self.callback();
            }
            self.counter++;
        }, speed);
    },
};

timer.start(function() {
    console.log('stopped');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: this makes it a lot more reusable, thank you Mikael for your explanation. Points out the same flaw in my thinking but also shows me how to make it more configurable. great!